2 PUT api request in same file in NEXT js
I need advice how to solve when I need for one route 2x PUT request. I need to add and remove two kinds of inputs, but I can remove one or the other. I can't figure out a way to set route.js to be able to add and remove both kinds of inputs.
export async function PUT(request) {
const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
const result = await CargoDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
{
   $and: [{ _id: id }],
 },
 {
   $push: { defaultValues: { count: "", long: "", width: "", 
 weight: "", high: "" },
   },
 },{ new: true }
);
return NextResponse.json({ result }, { status: 200 });
}

 export async function PUT(request) {
 const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
 const result = await CargoDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
     $and: [{ _id: id }],
   },
   {
     $push: {
       exwork: { cost: "" },
     },
   },
   { new: true }
 );

 return NextResponse.json({ result }, { status: 200 });
 }

Below you can see my Model for better idea:
const cargoDetailsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    defaultValues: { type: [formFields], default: undefined },
    exwork: { type: [exValue], default: undefined },
    client: String,
    sdl: String,
    price: Number,
    transport: String,
    menaFrom: String,
    menaTo: String,
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);

const CargoDetails =
  models?.CargoDetails || 
model("CargoDetails",cargoDetailsSchema);

export default CargoDetails;

defaultValues and exwork have their own plus and minus button for add and remove function.
I know that that maybe is it not possible to do it this way. I'd be grateful for any advice. .

i guess it can be easy, just add a action to request and define what kind of action you going to do, then use if statement and handle the request.

Could you please provide simply code example please?

add an action type to request query.
something like this
export async function PUT(request) {
 const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
 const action = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("action");
 let result;

 if (action === "actionA") {
  result = await CargoDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
    $and: [{ _id: id }],
   },
   {
    $push: {
     defaultValues: { count: "", long: "", width: "", weight: "", high: "" },
    },
   },
   { new: true },
  );
 } else if (action === "actionB") {
  result = await CargoDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
    $and: [{ _id: id }],
   },
   {
    $push: {
     exwork: { cost: "" },
    },
   },
   { new: true },
  );
 } else return NextResponse.json({ message:"Action not defined!" }, { status: 400 });

 return NextResponse.json({ result }, { status: 200 });
}


Yes, it works. This is exactly what I need. Many thanks for your help.
